# How to put a condition when using a parameter in Report Builder?

Tags: t-sql

I have a long SQL query and I'm trying to put a condition in order to insert data into the table (I use a Merge statement).
This condition looks like this:

AND e.EmployeeShortName = @EmployeeShortName

The Report Builder parameter have multiple EmployeeShortName and this condition works only when I select only one EmployeeShortName (it's a dropdown list). But if I select two EmployeeShortName or several, it won't work. I can understand why, but I cannot figure it out how to fix this.

I'm trying to use a condition in order to insert data into the table based on those condition, but cannot figure out how to use the parameter take multiple records into account.

Comment: its possibly creating a comma separated list, so you might need to use and `esn in (@esn)`

Comment: `e.EmployeeShortName = @EmployeeShortName` expects a *scalar* value. If you are passing multiple value, you need an `IN` (though I *hate* the way SSRS does it, as it *injects* those values and the syntax doesn't work like that in "normal" T-SQL).

Comment: Honestly, it's about 15 years overdue that SSRS supported table type parameters...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you correctly detected the reason as of why

```
AND e.EmployeeShortName = @EmployeeShortName
```

is working for a single element. Yet, if `@EmployeeShortName` is a comma-separated list, then you can do

```
AND e.EmployeeShortName in (@EmployeeShortName)
```

If it's not the case, then you will need to find out what's being generated after all and handle that query accordingly.